# Java generics - <K extends Middle> - is K a real child of Middle?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

The following method won't compile:

```
public <K extends Middle> K test(K a, K b) {

        return a.test(); //a.test() returns Middle
}
```

If we set `K` as a subtype of `Middle`, then `Middle` should be able to be returned, right?

If I do the following: `return (K)a.test();`, it compiles...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If we set K as a subtype of Middle, then Middle should be able to be returned, right?

No, this is not safe.  Take `Number` as an example.  If `Middle` is `Number` and `K` is `Integer`, `a.test()` could return a `Double` as `Double extends Number`.  But `Double` is not an `Integer`, so this would not be type safe.

All Ks are Middles, but it is not guaranteed that all Middles are Ks.

Comment: I still don't understand, a.test() will always return Middle.

Comment: @hrs: And your method is declared to return a `K`, not a `Middle`.  Not all Middles are Ks, so this isn't safe.

Comment: oooh, right. Obvious now. Thank you, that was really helpful.